# removeFromSuperview removes all subviews

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    NSLog(@"will rotation");

    for (UIButton *button in self.view.subviews) {
        [button removeFromSuperview];
    }

}
```

I have a problem with this code. I need to remove only UIButtons from my view. But this code also remove all subviews of my self.view. How can I solve this?

Comment: do you have one button or more

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do this:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
NSLog(@"will rotation");

   for (id subview in self.view.subviews) {
    if([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) //remove only buttons
    {
      [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }
   }

}
```

Comment: The provided example code isn't compilable -- `id` is a data type, not a variable name.

Answer (score 4):

You are iterating all the views and casting them to UIButton, not iterating UIButtons.
Try this:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    NSLog(@"will rotation");

    for (UIView *button in self.view.subviews) {
        if ([button isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            [button removeFromSuperview];
        }        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for (id button in self.view.subviews) 
    {
        if(button isKindOfClass:[UIButton class])
        {
          [button removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`self.view.subviews` will fetch all subviews, and using the type `UIButton *` in that way does not filter the list, it just hints to the compiler that you expect to be able to treat the objects like UIButtons. You must inspect each one, like this:

```
for (UIView *subview in self.view.subviews) {
    if([subview isKinfOfClass:[UIButton class]])
      [subview removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a tag at the top of the file

```
#define BUTTONSTODELETE 123
```

and then set each of the `buttons.tag = BUTTONSTODELETE`

Finally :

```
for (UIButton *v in [self.view subviews]){
        if (v.tag == BUTTONSTODELETE) {
            [v removeFromSuperview];
```

Guarantees only items with that tag will be removed

EDIT: Maulik and fbernardo have a better, less messy way